# NodeJS creating JSON using all JSONs uploaded by user

Tags: json, node.js

I am trying to make a JSON file using all the JSON files in a directory. Every time a user uploads a new JSON a new combined JSON should be generated. I want the new JSON to have a custom structure hence cant use any libraries. I have the following code:

```
    router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

var sampleFile;
var bbbid = req.body.bbbid;
DDLFile = req.files.DDLFile;


j++;

DDLFile.mv('/uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + j + '.json', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    else {
        res.redirect("fileuploaded");
    }

});


var myfiles = [];
var fs = require('fs');

var arrayOfFiles = fs.readdirSync('/uploads/' + bbbid);

arrayOfFiles.forEach(function (file) {
    myfiles.push(file);
    console.log(myfiles);
});
console.log('No of Files:', myfiles.length);
var files = myfiles.length;
console.log('Files:', files);
console.log('J', j);

var cddl = "{ BBBID:" + bbbid;
if (files == 0) {

    cddl = cddl + '}';
    console.log('Entered if loop');

}
else {
    var i = 0;
    /*var obj;
    fs.readFile('/uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + j + '.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
    });*/

    for (i = 0; i < files; i++) {
        console.log('Entered For loop');
        console.log('Count:', count);
        console.log('Sensor:', sensor);
        try{
        var obj = fs.readFileSync('/uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + count + '.json', 'utf8');}
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('everything good');
        var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
        console.log('hi');
        //JSON.stringify(obj);
        var ddl = require('/uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + count + '.json');
        console.log('o');
        cddl = cddl + ", {" + obj1.DDL.Sensor.Description.Verbose_Description + ":" + JSON.stringify(ddl) + "}"
        JSON.stringify(cddl);
        console.log(cddl);
        count++;
        sensor++;
        console.log('Count:', count);
        console.log('Sensor:', sensor);
    }
    cddl = cddl + '}';
    JSON.stringify(cddl);
    console.log(cddl);
}
```

});

I want to generate a new cddl everytime a new file is uploaded. Having a lot of problems. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems. First instead of this:

```
 var obj = fs.readFileSync('/uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + count + '.json', 'utf8');}
 catch(err){
     console.log(err);
 }
 console.log('everything good');
 var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj);
```

You can write(fix path, if necessary):

```
var obj1 = require('./uploads/' + bbbid + '/device' + count + '.json')
```

Then, when you call:

```
JSON.stringify(cddl);
```

You're not saving the result anywhere. So you should save it in the place, you need to:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(cddl);
```

And when all set, dont forget to write to file back using [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) or async one [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

Comment: gives an error saying Unexpected end of Json input. Also says 'Can't set headers after they are sent.' on the console

Comment: First - make sure, you provide valid json. Second error - means you already send headers somewhere else.